# How do I test is a Python variable is a set

Tags: python

If I have an object:

```
w = {'A'}
```

how do I test if this is a set or not?

Comment: `isinstance` is a builtin, but type-checking is generally discouraged in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if isinstance(w, set):
```

Add this if statement to check, replace w with the variable you want to check.